# Git retrieve config settings using a wildcard

Tags: git

I'm learning git and I'm trying to figure out whether it's possible to get all config settings of a certain type using just git.

For example:

```
git config --get core.symlinks
```

This looks through all config settings and returns the values for each setting found. Filtering for specific configs like `--global` is pretty straightforward too. Now I'm wondering whether it's possible to get all settings of a certain category of settings, like getting all settings prefixed with core.:

```
git config --get core'.*' //doesn't work, the documentation does suggest a [value_regex]
```

Is something like this at all possible or should I just get used to pipelines and grep?

```
$ git config --list | grep core
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
git config --get-regexp core'\.'
```